# what is the postman body type of chrome's fetch API body option?

Tags: postman

I am using postman to send requests so that i can test and debug my backend REST API. For the backend I am using ExpressJS. However, when trying to access req.body within an endpoint I am getting undefined on backend unlike using body in chrome window.fetch method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

> **body**
>
> Any body that you want to add to your request: this can be a Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, USVString, or ReadableStream object. Note that a request using the GET or HEAD method cannot have a body.

The `Content-Type` header set by `fetch` will depend on which type of value you pass to it.

e.g. if you pass a `FormData` object then it will use an internal API on that object to generate the Content-Type header (which will be `multipart/form-data` with a `boundary` parameter) while if you pass a `URLSearchParams` object then it will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

That assumes the header isn't overwritten by the JS calling `fetch` though.

---

You can use the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to monitor the request sent by `fetch` and see what Content-Type is set for it.